# CakePHP search query on link

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following link: `<?php echo $this->Html->link('Students', 
                    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search', 'students'),  array('title' => 'Students')); ?>`

which produces this: `/users/search/students`

BUT I want it to produce this instead: `/users/search:q=students`

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Students',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search', 'search' => 'q=students'),
    array('title' => 'Students'));
```